# checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPayment' doesn't exist on type 'Mutation'

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node, shopify-storefront-api

I want to place order by COD using storefront qraphql Sopify

I am building a GraphQL Store front API in Shopify, and I have encountered an error where the 'checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPayment' mutation is not recognized on the 'Mutation' type. Here are the details:

I am working on a Shopify Store front GraphQL. I have a Mutation type defined in my schema, but when I try to use the 'checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPayment' mutation, I receive the following error:

````
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Field 'checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPaymentV2' doesn't exist on type 'Mutation'",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "mutation",
                "checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPaymentV2"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "undefinedField",
                "typeName": "Mutation",
                "fieldName": "checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPaymentV2"
            }
        }
    ]
}```

and my mutation is bellow 

```mutation {
  checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPayment(checkoutId: "checkout id", payment: {
    paymentAmount: {
      amount: "5009.1",
      currencyCode: "INR"
    },
    idempotencyKey: "key",
    billingAddress: {
      address1: "123 Main St",
      city: "City",
      province: "Province",
      country: "Country",
      zip: "12345"
    },
    paymentData: {
      type: CASH_ON_DELIVERY
    }
  }) {
    checkout {
      id
      order {
        id
      }
    }
    checkoutUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: isn't it `checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPaymentV3` mutation ?